# Using collection to filter

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, collection, filter

How would I use

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

to only return products that have a special price and my own custom attribute set to yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code and let me know

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',1) //here  custom_attribute is attribute_code 
                ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                           Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                           Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
               )) //showing just products visible in catalog or both search and catalog
               ->addFinalPrice()
               ->getSelect()
               ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');
```

Comment: add `addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',1)`

Comment: @GopalPatel I didn't get you this time

Comment: Refer question `and my own custom attribute set to yes`